# How to cast object returned from Module

Tags: java, java-module, java-platform-module-system

I trying `ModuleLayer` with JDK 11, I have created two modules `Implementation` and `Model`. Consider the `Implementation` module provides a method which returns an object which is of type `Foo`, the class `Foo` is defined in `Model` module.

So module `Implementation` `requires Model;` and module `Model` exports all its namespaces.

I a separate application, I am creating  `Configuration` to resolve both the modules and created `ModuleLayer` as well. By using `layer.findLoader("Implementation").loadClass()` I have loaded a class from `Implementation` module and invoked static method using `method.invoke(null, "test");`
which returns an `Object`.

Now I don't understand, how should I can cast this object to `Foo`? I cannot use `(Foo) obj` because the jar of `Model` module is not on classpath. and even if I put it I end up with exception

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.test.model.Foo cannot be cast to class com.test.model.Foo (com.test.model.Foo is in module Model of loader jdk.internal.loader.Loader @e9b78b0; com.test.model.Foo is in unnamed module of loader com.company.container.internal.Interpreters$ClassLoaders$$anon$1 @45815ffc)`

```
Object provider=null;
try
{
   var path = Path.of(Core.getConfiguration().getBasePath().getPath() ,"\\model\\lib\\EC");
   ModuleFinder finder = ModuleFinder.of(path);
   var parent = ModuleLayer.boot();
   Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(finder, ModuleFinder.of(), Set.of("Implementation"));
   ClassLoader scl = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); // intentionally using this class's loader  
   ModuleLayer layer = parent.defineModulesWithOneLoader(cf, scl);
   var cl = layer.findLoader("Implementation");
   Class<?> classTest = cl.loadClass("com.test.AutoConfiguration");
   var method = classSendMailFromX.getMethod("getProvider", String.class);
   provider = method.invoke(null, "test");
}
catch (Exception e) {
   throw new CoreException(e);
}
if(provider == null)
{
   throw new Exception("provider cannot be empty");
}

var myProvider = (Foo) provider; // This line compiles but calls fails at runtime if I put `Model` module jar on classpath
```

I understand the reason, that any jar (even if it is a module) at classpath will be treated as unnamed module. But, why I cannot able to cast it? And is there any way to do it?

Comment: Your problem is entirely unrelated to modules. If you load class `Foo` through `Interpreters$ClassLoaders$$anon$1@45815ffc` and another class `Foo` through `Loader@e9b78b0`, these are different classes. Whether these `Foo` classes belong to a module, doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

The comment from @Holger names the problem: That `Foo` isn't `Foo` as soon as they are both loaded by different class/module loaders.

Let me sketch two different approaches:

### Solution1: The module way

The goal here is to have class `Foo` only loaded once.
To achieve this the application with the code above should be in a module as well and require `Model`:

```java
module App {
    requires Model;
}
```

To make this work you have additionally to avoid having `Model` loaded a second time through the presented code. This can be achieved either (a) by *not* having it placed into `"\\model\\lib\\EC"`. Or by (b) changing the order of `ModuleFinder`s in `Configuration.resolve()`:

```
Configuration cf = parent.configuration().resolve(ModuleFinder.of(), finder. Set.of("Implementation"));
```

This way `Implementation` will use the version of `Model` present in the module path of the calling code and not load it via `finder`.

### Solution 2: Use a proxy

This requires `Foo` to be an interface.

You could have a method `proxyOf` that looks like this:

```java
    private Foo proxyOf(Object result) {
        InvocationHandler handler = (proxy, method, args) -> {
            Method delegate = result.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            return delegate.invoke(result, args);
        };
        return (Foo) Proxy.newProxyInstance(this.getClass().getClassLoader(), new Class[]{ Foo.class }, handler);
    }
```

This way you can have two versions of `Foo`. You just have to get sure, that the application code is actually allowed to access method `delegate`. So it (and the containing implementation class) must either be `public` or you will need an additional `delegate.setAccessible(true);` before calling it. If the application is within a module (like in Solution 1), the package of `delegate` must be opened through the `opens` clause:

```java
module Implementation {
    requires transitive Model;
    exports org.example.impl;
    opens org.example.impl;
}
```

Please not that there is a ***major pitfall*** in the proxy solution: It works well as long as you are passing types of the JRE, but as soon as you pass your own types `method.getParameterTypes()` will return the wrong types leading to a `NoSuchMethodException`. Even when you manage to get the correct types you would need to pass proxies of that types. Then all this will get *really* complicated and you will end up with your own little "back and forth proxyfication" framework.

### Final notes

Unfortunately you do not describe what you *actually* want to achieve. So we cannot know what problem you want to solve with it and why you need the code above. Honestly, it seems quite difficult to me that your code could be maintained by someone else. Maybe you could achieve the same thing by using [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html)?